# Qt Translation returns the same string instead of translation

Tags: qt

I am experiencing a strange Qt Translation problem.

Due to reasons I cannot change that involve legacy databases of translation tables, our 'natural language' is 'Enums'.

```
QString myString = tr("OUR_APP_MY_STRING");
```

I have a script that builds the *.TS files out of our databases to be used by Qt.

The entry in the *.TS files for english looks like this:

```
<message>
    <source>OUR_APP_MY_STRING</source>
    <translation>My String</translation>
</message>
```

The *.TS file loads fine into Qt Linguist. Everything there looks fine. "OUR_APP_MY_STRING" is found and its "English Translation" looks ok.

The QT project file has the *.TS files in the TRANSLATION sections
I am using lRelease to generate the *.QM files and putting them in the application's resources (*.qrc) file.

In my application's setup function (called by main() after construction) I have the following code:

```
// initialize translator
this->currentTranslator = new QTranslator(instance());

if (this->currentTranslator->load(":/translation/myApp_en.qm"))
{
  this->installTranslator(this->currentTranslator);
  QString test = tr("OUR_APP_MY_STRING");  // <<----- problem. output is always "OUR_APP_MY_STRING"

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear what is `instance()` in this line

```
 this->currentTranslator = new QTranslator(instance());
```

But anyway, here's some things to check:

- Do you have something like this in `YourProjectName.pro` ?

> ```
> RESOURCES += \
>    resources.qrc
> ```

(`resources.qrc` is the name I usually use. Replace with whatever name you choose.)

- Did you check the prefixes in your `resources.qrc` ? Are you sure there's a `translation/` prefix in there? Something like this should also work:

> ```
>   <RCC>
>     <qresource prefix="/">
>       <file>translation/YourProjectName_en.qm</file>
>       <!-- other resources here -->
>     </qresource>
>   </RCC>
> ```

provided that you have `YourProjectName_en.qm` in a `translation/` subdirectory.

This is what ***Works for Me™***:

in `main.cpp`:

```
 QApplication app(argc, argv);
 QApplication::setApplicationName("MyApplication");
 QApplication::setApplicationVersion("4.4");
 QApplication::setOrganizationName("FUBAR");
 QApplication::setOrganizationDomain("www.fu.bar");

 QTranslator translator;
 translator.load(app.applicationName() + "_" + QLocale::system().name(), ":/ts");
 app.installTranslator(&translator);
```

in `resources.qrc`:

> ```
> <RCC>
>    <qresource prefix="/">
>      <file>resources/pixmaps/exit.png</file>
>      <!-- ... -->
>      <file>ts/MyApplication_en.qm</file>
>      <file>ts/MyApplication_es.qm</file>
>    </qresource>
> </RCC>
> ```

in `MyApplication.pro`:

```
 TRANSLATIONS += \
   ts/MyApplication_en.ts \
   ts/MyApplication_es.ts

 RESOURCES += \
   resources.qrc

 win32 {
   RC_FILE = win32.rc
 }

 OTHER_FILES += \
     win32.rc \
     TODO.txt
```

And here's a brief description of the project tree:

```
MyApplication
 ├── resources
 │   ├── pixmaps
 │   └── ...
 ├── (sources are here)
 ├── MyApplication.pro
 ├── resources.qrc
 ├── TODO.txt
 ├── ts
 │   ├── MyApplication_en.qm
 │   ├── MyApplication_en.ts
 │   ├── MyApplication_es.qm
 │   └── MyApplication_es.ts
 └── win32.rc
```

This is a very small project, sources are mixed with a few artifacts.

**Edit:**

I think you should try passing the filename and directory parts separated to the load method. In short, change this line

```
 if (this->currentTranslator->load(":/translation/myApp_en.qm"))
```

to this

```
 if (this->currentTranslator->load("myApp_en.qm", ":/translation/"))
```

Comment: To Answer your questions: yes, I have the *.qrc file in my project file. All my apps images are there. *.qrc file prefix is "/". Folders are present. The only difference between us is that i load and initialize the translator from within my QApplication derived class, and you're doing it from within the main method.

Comment: It's not the loading part. I gave up resources just to see where the problem us. I load directly from my hard drive, and loading is fine. the load returns "true".. the "isEmpty" on the QTranslator returns false. I think I am having trouble because my *.TS files are UTF-8 as my app is translated to 13 languages, some quite exotic. I can't figure out how to fix it. translating a string always returns the same string, untranslated.

Comment: @dschulz is there a variable in the project file for qrc_resources files to gather them in a folder like `MOC_DIR` for `.moc` files?

Comment: @Niklas there's `RCC_DIR` for resource files in general, but I'm not sure that's what you want. You can always classify your resource files as you want in whatever directory structure you see fit, and then just correctly define the paths to individual files in your `.qrc` file.